# Создание и добавление новых полей настроек Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

Добрый день!
Изобретаю велосипед, но хочется/нужно/требуют, чтоб так и было.
Суть проблемы такова.
Есть слайдер, на главной странице сайта на WP.
В админке создана страница с его настройками...
Два поля, в одном из них изображение (загрузчик уже подключен), в другом текст слайда.
Очень хочется, чтоб при нажатии на кнопку, сохранялось текущее поле и добавлялось еще одно такое же ниже...
Затуп в том, как реализовать создание нового поля? и куда девать сохраненные значения? в массив? Как потом выдрать значение?
До этого делал через мета-поля к странице/записи, а потом циклом while выдирал данные...

Comment: Да, массив. Скачайте мой плагин woof by category из репозитория WP и посмотрите, как сделаны настройки. Реализовано ровно то, о чем вы говорите. Завтра напишу ответ с примером.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рассмотрим в качестве примера мой небольшой плагин WOOF by Category, который можно [скачать из официального репозитория WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woof-by-category/). Страница настроек выглядит в нем таким образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждой выбранной категории сопоставляется набор фильтров. В php коде настройки представлены массивом ассоциативных массивов. Так выглядит вывод переменной `$options` в отладчике PhpStorm после загрузки опций из базы:

```
$options = get_option( 'woof_by_category_settings' ); // Get current settings.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание, что последний элемент массива `$options[2]` содержит пустые значения. Именно поэтому в третьей группе на странице настроек вы видите приглашение <kbd>--Выберите категорию--</kbd> и пустой muliselect с фильтрами.

Если пользователь сделал выбор в третьей группе, то в базу будет записан массив опций с непустыми значениями `$options[2]`. Тогда при следующей инициализации плагина (а она производится WordPress после нажатия на кнопку <kbd>Сохранить изменения</kbd>, из массива опций удаляется пустое значение, если оно есть, массив повторно индексируется, а потом в конец массива всегда добавляется пустое значение и опции сохраняются в базу:

```
$options = get_option( 'woof_by_category_settings' ); // Get current settings.
if ( $options ) {
    foreach ( $options as $key => $value ) {
        if ( ! $value['category'] ) {
            unset( $options[ $key ] ); // Remove group with empty categories.
        }
    }
}

$options = array_values( $options ); // Reindex settings array.

// Add empty group to the end.
$count             = count( $options );
$options[ $count ] = array(
    'category' => '',
    'filters'  => array(),
);
$count ++;

update_option( 'woof_by_category_settings', $options ); // Save settings.
```

Такой код позволяет иметь неограниченный набор настроек (в моем случае пар категория=>перечень фильтров) и всегда в конце выводить пустую секцию для добавления новых настроек.

Удаление пустых секций в массиве в приведенном выше коде позволяет сбрасывать ненужные настройки. Например, на картинке есть секция с категорией <kbd>Quisquam (7)</kbd>. Если пользователь в этом select выберет <kbd>--Выберите фильтры--</kbd>, то элемент массива будет сброшен, при реиндексации удален, и пользователь увидит обновленную страницу настроек уже без секции с <kbd>Quisquam (7)</kbd>.

Механизм построения страницы настроек в данном плагине основан на API настроек WordPress. Подробнее об этом API можно почитать на русском языке [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/id_3773/api-optsiy-nastroek.html).